# lenovo SK 8821 hotkeys not working after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 22.04, keyboard, lenovo

Yesterday, I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04LTS on my desktop PC. It automatically updated all the packages. Today I noticed that the hotkeys of my [Lenovo SK 8821](https://support.lenovo.com/ro/en/downloads/ds019629) is not working. These hotkeys functioned perfectly for the last two years without any need for manual configuration. The keyboard is using "Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard", I don't remember what it was when using with 20.04.
I did a `showkey` test.

- When I press F1 (which is mapped to mute), it registers as keycode 113. ChatGPT told me this is indeed the keycode for the mute function.
- When I press Fn + F1 (which is the actual F1 key), it registers as keycode 59. This is the standard keycode for F1.

```sh
╰─ sudo showkey   
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 release
keycode 113 press
keycode 113 release
^[OPkeycode  59 press
keycode  59 release
```

I have verified that my keyboard layout is set to UK, which is the same as it was before the upgrade. I'm looking for any insights or suggestions on how to get these hotkeys working again in Ubuntu 22.04. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I am using 2 keyboard and 2 mouse setup for a long time. The other keyboard is Dell and the two mice are Dell and [this unbranded mouse](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wireless-Vertical-Function-Ergonomic-Undetectable-Black/dp/B09W9B6HN6/). Here is the output of `cat /var/log/syslog | grep keyboard`:

```sh
Jan  2 17:53:47 VIG450J systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.
Jan  2 17:53:47 VIG450J kernel: [    8.206749] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
Jan  2 17:53:52 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event13 - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event13 - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event7  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event7  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event10 - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event10 - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event9  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event9  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event4  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event4  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event5  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event5  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event14 - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (II) event14 - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:53:53 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2017]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event13 - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event13 - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event7  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event7  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event10 - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event10 - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event9  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event9  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event4  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event4  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event5  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event5  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event14 - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event14 - Eee PC WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 17:54:28 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 17:54:34 VIG450J systemd[2723]: Starting GNOME keyboard configuration service...
Jan  2 17:54:34 VIG450J systemd[2723]: Starting GNOME keyboard shortcuts service...
Jan  2 17:54:34 VIG450J systemd[2723]: Started GNOME keyboard configuration service.
Jan  2 17:54:34 VIG450J systemd[2723]: Reached target GNOME keyboard configuration target.
Jan  2 17:54:34 VIG450J systemd[2723]: Started GNOME keyboard shortcuts service.
Jan  2 17:54:34 VIG450J systemd[2723]: Reached target GNOME keyboard shortcuts target.
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event7  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event7  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event9  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event9  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event10 - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event10 - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event13 - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:15:54 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event13 - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:06 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:06 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event5  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:06 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event5  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:06 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:06 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:06 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event4  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:06 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event4  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:09 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:09 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event7  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:09 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event7  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:10 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:10 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event9  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:10 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event9  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:10 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:10 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:10 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event10 - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:10 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event10 - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:10 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:10 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event13 - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:10 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event13 - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:22 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:22 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event5  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:22 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event5  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:22 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:22 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event4  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:22 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event4  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:22 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:30 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:30 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event5  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:30 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event5  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:30 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:30 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event4  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:30 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event4  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:30 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:38 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:38 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event4  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:38 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event4  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:38 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:38 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event5  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:38 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event5  - Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:38 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) Lite-On Technology Corp. Lenovo USB Keyboard Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event7  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event7  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event10 - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event10 - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event9  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event9  - MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (**) DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event13 - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device is a keyboard
Jan  2 18:16:40 VIG450J /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2846]: (II) event13 - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device is a keyboard
```